# What is the absolute value of empty set? |{∅}|=1 ? why ? thank you

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As the title, namely. I read something like this and not deeply understand the reason. Please explain and thank you in advance.

1. List item

T(0) ={∅}, T(1)= {1}. so |T(∅)|=1 and |T(1)|=1

Comment: Can you please tell me what is it? thank you.

Comment: What is $T$?  Also, $|A|$ for a set $A$ is the *cardinality* of $A$, not “absolute value”

Comment: @ Matthew Leingang. Thank you. it is cardinality of something. not the absolute value.

Comment: $\{\emptyset\}$ is the set containing the empty set, not the empty set itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\{\emptyset\}$ is not the [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set). $\{\}$ is. $\{\emptyset\}$ is a set containing one element and this element is the empty set.

[Added:] the two bars in $|\{\emptyset\}|$ denote the "[cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality)" of the set $\{\emptyset\}$; they are not called the "absolute value".

Comment: Either $\{\}$ or $\emptyset$ is the empty set, but not both (that is, not $\{\emptyset\}$)!

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: I'm a bit confused by your comment. *Both* the notations $\{\}$ and $\emptyset$ denote the "empty set". When you say "not both", you mean "the symbol $\{\emptyset\}$ is not the empty", right? (So "both" means "put them together"?)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say (and the original comment was in support of your answer, not critical of it): one may write $\{\}$ for the empty set, or one may write $\emptyset$, but one may not write both simultaneously, as in $\{\emptyset\}$.  That, as you correctly point out, is something different altogether.